# returning a new list with names and grades converted to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with this function.
Can anyone please help me fix it?

```
def string_list(L):
    '''(list of str) -> list of list
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' return a new list of 
    lists where each inner list has the format :
    [name (str), grade, grade, grade, ...] where the name 
    is a string and the grades are floats.

>>> string_list(['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98'])
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
'''
new_string_list = []
for grades in L:
    if grades.isnumeric():
        grades = float(grades)
        new_string_list.append([grades])
        for name in L:
            if name.isalpha():
                new_string_list.append([name])
return new_string_list.append([name, grades])
```

Comment: Just for fun, there is a one-liner: `[[i[:i.index(',')], *[float(s) for s in i[i.index(',')+1:].split(',')]] for i in g]` ... where `g` is your input list. If this is a homework problem, you probably won't get away with that.

Comment: Is there an efficient  way to do it using a function?

Comment: Are you asking whether the one line is efficient? Because "in a function" would just entail writing `def string_list(g):` and then the body of the function with `return` followed by that expression. There are multiple answers below, and some of the comments have even better one-liners than the one I just threw out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
students = ['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
result = []
for item in students:
  parts = item.split(', ')
  item_result = parts[:1] + [float(y) for y in parts[1:]]
  result.append(item_result)
print(result)
# [['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

Comment: What are you using the `i` for? Won't it work okay with just `for item in students`?

Comment: Streamlined: `result = [parts[:1] + [float(y) for y in parts[1:]] for parts in (item.split(', ') for item in students)]`

Comment: @ray-toal Just a habit that helps with debugging. 'i' does not hurt but you are right, it is redundant here

Comment: Where does y come from?

Comment: @dg123, in expression `[float(y) for y in parts[1:]]` variable `y` would be assigned an element from the list `parts[1:]` one by one

Comment: so y would be the grades then?

Comment: Is there another way to write that line?

Comment: Here is another way. Inefficient, but hopefully more selfexplanatory `>>> item_result = [] >>>item_results.append(parts[0]) # add last name as a first element of the list >>> for grage in parts[1:]: >>>  item_results.append(float(grade)) # add grade to the end of the list`

Comment: Could you explain it using a function?

Comment: Got it to work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
stringList = ['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
[ [j[0]]+[float(k) for k in j[1:]] for j in [i.split(', ') for i in stringList] ]
```

Output:

```
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0],
 ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0],
 ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski - I overlooked. Thanks for pointing. Just fixed it.

Comment: This works, but do note that the specification is positional, not situational: "each inner list has the format :
    [name (str), grade, grade, grade, ...] where the name 
    is a string and the grades are floats".

Comment: @Steven, Right, thanks. Please see my latest update.

Answer (score 0):

just a list comprehension :

```
>>> a
['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
>>> r=[[float(j) if j.replace('.', '').isdigit()  else j for j in i.split(", ")] for i in a]
>>> r
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

if you check the index :

```
>>> a=['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
>>> r=[[float(j) if i.split(", ").index(j)!=0 else j for j in i.split(", ")] for i in a]
>>> r
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

Comment: Look at your result.  All items are still strings.

Comment: oh yes sorry, but I edited.

Comment: This works, but do note that the specification is positional, not situational: "each inner list has the format : [name (str), grade, grade, grade, ...] where the name is a string and the grades are floats".

Comment: Ah, yes understood, I edited my post with a solution checking the index

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

> Two line solution:

```
list_1=['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']

split_it=[str(i).replace(",","").split() for i in list_1]


print([i[:1]+[float(j) for j in i[1:]] for i in split_it])
```

output:

```
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

> Detailed solution :

The first step split your string so that we can iterate over each element :

```
split_it=[]  #storing new splited result here 

for i in list_1:
    split_it.append(str(i).replace(",","").split())

print(split_it)
[['Anna', '50', '90', '80'], ['Bill', '60', '70'], ['Cal', '98.5', '100', '95.5', '98']]
```

Now next step is iterate through each sublist and leave the first element since its str and convert rest of them into float:

I suggest you should know about how actually list comprehension works before using them :

```
list=[i for i in a]
```

> is same as :

```
list=[]
for i in a:
    list.append(i)
```

Now back to the solution :

```
float_list=[]
for i in split_it:
    sub_list=[]
    for j in i[1:]:
        sub_list.append(float(j))

    float_list.append(i[:1]+sub_list)

print(float_list)
```

> All combine:

```
list_1=['Anna, 50, 90, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']


split_it=[]  #storing new splited result here

for i in list_1:
    split_it.append(str(i).replace(",","").split())


float_list=[]
for i in split_it:
    sub_list=[]
    for j in i[1:]:
        sub_list.append(float(j))

    float_list.append(i[:1]+sub_list)

print(float_list)
```

Ouput:

```
[['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
```

Comment: So essentially you are using 3 for loops?

Comment: Yes , 3 loops, But there are other solution too if you are facing complexity issue.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: @dg123 i gave you two solution one is two lines and second one is detailed. I tried my best to make you understand how exactly program is working because there are many solutions but you should first understand how its working so that you can implement yourself. if you are still facing any issue while understanding my code , let me know i will add more explanation. :)

Comment: In your second solution, why are you splitting and replacing "" at the same time?

Comment: You can try this in terminal , if i don't replace then it will give this output:

`[['Anna,', '50,', '90,', '80'], ['Bill,', '60,', '70'], ['Cal,', '98.5,', '100,', '95.5,', '98']]`

Comment: [['Anna509080']] I got that when I tested the whole thing. Are the indents all right?

Comment: @dg123 i think you run the half code. I have updated the solution and added the combine code of all steps in one place run that last code.

Comment: I get this now [['Anna', 50.0], ['Anna', 50.0, 90.0], ['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]

Comment: I test many times on my machine , its working perfect , I don't know why you are facing error. can you pastebin the error ?

Comment: Expected:
    [['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]]
Got:
    [['Anna', 50.0], ['Anna', 50.0, 90.0], ['Anna', 50.0, 90.0, 80.0], ['Bill', 60.0], ['Bill', 60.0, 70.0], ['Cal', 98.5], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5], ['Cal', 98.5, 100.0, 95.5, 98.0]] I got that when I tested it

Comment: @dg123  i don't know what wrong with your machine , please click on this link  https://repl.it/MOoW/0   and test yourself its working perfect.        https://repl.it/MOoW/0

Comment: I got what I showed in my previous comment when I test it in my machine. I just want the first two sublists removed for each name

Comment: @dg123  have you seen this link repl.it/MOoW/0   , its working perfect online compiler here repl.it/MOoW/0    as you want , i don't know about your machine may be you are running wrong code or what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156137/discussion-between-ayodhyankit-paul-and-dg123).